# Code fails on Test case. (InterQuartile Range)

Tags: statistics, range, python-3.6

This is a challenge from 10 Day statistics on Hackerrank.(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/s10-interquartile-range/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)

Task :
Task
The interquartile range of an array is the difference between its first (Q1) and third (Q3) quartiles (i.e., Q3 - Q1).

Given an array,X, of n integers and an array, F, representing the respective frequencies of X's elements, construct a data set, S, where each  xi occurs at frequency fi. Then calculate and print S's interquartile range, rounded to a scale of 1 decimal place (i.e., 12.3 format).

Following is my code.

```
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int, input().split()))

f = list(map(int, input().split()))

s = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    j = f[i]
    for k in range(j):
        s.append(x[i])
n = len(s)

s.sort()
if n%2 == 0:
    Q21 = s[n//2]
    Q22 = s[n//2 - 1]
    Q2 = (Q21 + Q22) / 2
else:
    Q2 = s[n//2]

LH = s[:n//2]
if n%2==0:
    UH = s[n//2:]
else:
    UH = s[n//2+1:]

Q1_len = len(LH)
Q3_len = len(UH)
if Q1_len%2 == 0:
    Q11 = LH[Q1_len//2]
    Q12 = LH[Q1_len//2 - 1]
    Q1 = (Q11 + Q12) / 2
else:
    Q1 = LH[Q1_len//2]

if Q3_len%2 == 0:
    Q31 = UH[Q3_len//2]
    Q32 = UH[Q3_len//2 - 1]
    Q3 = (Q31 + Q32) / 2
else:
    Q3 = UH[Q3_len//2]

print(round(Q3 - Q1,1))
# print(int(Q2))
# print(int(Q3))
```

Here is the test case: with std input.

```
5

10 40 30 50 20

1 2 3 4 5
```

Expected output:

```
30.0
```

My code output:

```
30.0 # I get this output on my code editor but not on Hackerrank
```

Can someone help me on this where I am wrong ?

I get the output what is expected but it shows as failed.

Comment: Question is Solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(float(Q3 - Q1))
```

Basically is the answer.